# How to run an existing shell script using airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I wanted to run some existing bash scripts using airflow without modifying the code in the script itself. Is it possible without mentioning the shell commands in the script in a task?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if understood your question, but you can load your shell commands into 
 Variables through Admin >> Variables menu as a json file.
And in your dag read the variable and pass as parameter into the BashOperator.

Airflow variables in more detail:
https://www.applydatascience.com/airflow/airflow-variables/

Example of variables file:
https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial/blob/v0.7/examples/intro-example/dags/config/example_variables.json

How to read the variable:
https://github.com/tuanavu/airflow-tutorial/blob/v0.7/examples/intro-example/dags/example_variables.py

I hope this post helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the shell script is on the same machine that the Airflow Worker is running you can just call the shell script using the Bash Operator like the following:

```
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_example',

    # Just call the script
    bash_command="/home/batcher/test.sh ",
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to 'link' your local folder where your shell script is with worker, which means that you need to add volume in worker part of your docker-compose file..

so I added volume line under worker settings and worker now looks at this folder on your local machine:

```html
airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /LOCAL_MACHINE_FOLDER/WHERE_SHELL_SCRIPT_IS:/folder_in_root_folder_of_worker
```